# Linux distributions won't work right graphically?

Tags: linux, debian, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, integrated-graphics

I'm trying to install a Debian based Linux operating system on my Desktop. However, it seems to be a common theme across all Linux distributions I've tried to install so far is that they just simply don't work.

They take five years to start up, usually with a bunch of switching between a black and dark grey screen. And then once it finally does start up, it either goes into a login loop when I try to login, or my screen decides to have a stroke and go all crazy, then freeze and die.

From what I've heard, this is a problem with my GPU. My system doesn't even have a dedicated GPU, but it does have a small, integrated one. Specs:

```
CPU: AMD Athlon II X3 445
RAM: 8GB
GPU: NVIDIA MCP61 (integrated)
HDD: 2TB
Motherboard: BIOSTAR N68S3B
```

I'm sure that probably some of those specs are completely useless in terms of relevancy to the problem, but I always seem to get yelled at whenever I don't give enough information.

So far I've tried to install Kali, Ubuntu, and Elementary. They've all been very similar in terms of behavior, which is just to altogether not work.

It also did the same thing in the LiveUSB Installer, until I found out I could select the normal boot-up, but the ACPI off, in the GRUB menu. But then whenever I actually installed the OS, and then rebooted, the option to boot without ACPI was suddenly gone. I'm not sure how to get that back.

How do I get a Debian-Linux OS to work properly on my Desktop?

Comment: This seems more like a complaint than a question...

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: SE is not about reading between the lines, SE is about getting searchable answers to questions. So the more straightforward the question (and especially its title), the more it can benefit others.

Comment: @EthanWaldeck , welcome to SuperUser.  Please edit your question to/ remove hypebole (five years).  Please include the motherboard make/model.  Please try a LiveCD and let us know if it boots and works normally in the pre-installed test phase.

Comment: SE is a great community resource. It's designed so you can hopefully just do a search to find your answer and if not, then post a question. It's not your private site to demand answers. If you're down voted, then there is a problem with your post. Poor posts get down voted because they don't benefit the community. It's easy to fix your question and move on but you chose to take a defensive route instead.

Comment: It sounds like you are saying you were able to boot when you disable ACPI. This is possible to do on the command line to grub, so you may want to look into how to modify your boot line (for whichever options you are trying to boot) to include `acpi=off`. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/160036/how-do-i-disable-acpi-when-booting

Answer (score 1):

Use the [driver provided by NVIDIA](https://www.nvidia.com/object/linux_nforce_amd64_1.0-0292.html) I found as the first result when I did a web search on *Linux NVIDIA MCP61*, after you have made a [Debian LiveUSB installer](https://www.debian.org/CD/live/), installed it, and booted with the [nomodeset option edited into](https://support.reliablesite.net/kb/a240/how-to-set-nomodeset-into-the-grub-bootloader-debian-and-ubuntu-intel-core-i7-3770.aspx) [GRUB](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/).

- Please ignore the references to a specific Intel CPU and to servers
  in the *nomodeset* instructions above.

Comment: That old driver won't work for any currently supported kernel or anything else from 10 years ago or older. The truth is the whole system is too old for anything barely resembling an usable OS. It may (barely) work with something like AntiX but using the `nouveau` driver but it depends on the community having kept support for such ancient Nvidia chipsets.